# Disable / hide accessibility element

Tags: macos, voiceover

I'm trying to hide several elements in my app from VoiceOver so that they don't get read aloud by the screen reader. On iOS, I'd set `isAccessibilityElement` to `NO`, but this has no effect on OSX. What's the correct way to go about hiding elements from VoiceOver?

For example, I have a series of labels contained inside a view that make no sense if they're spoken separately by VoiceOver. I'd like to set the `accessibilityLabel` on the container view to describe all the labels nested within. But if I do that, the labels inside are still read out by VoiceOver.

Answer (score 5):

In macOS, it is true that setting `accessibilityElement` to `NO` for `NSButton`, `NSTextField` and `NSImageView` has no effect.  That is because these are *controls* – they inherit from `NSControl`.  To make it work for *controls*, you must do it instead to the control's ***cell***.

In an Objective-C project, I so subclassed several Cocoa controls.  For example, whenever I want a image view to be skipped by VoiceOver, I set its Custom Class in Interface Builder to this:

```
/*!
 @brief    Image view which will be skipped over by VoiceOver

 @details  Be careful that you *really* want the view to be skipped over by
 VoiceOver, because its meaning is conveyed in a better, non-visual way,
 elsewhere.  Remember that not all VoiceOver users are completely blind.
  */
@interface SSYNoVoiceOverImageView : NSImageView {}
@end

@implementation SSYNoVoiceOverImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.cell.accessibilityElement = NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: No subclassing needed, just use the Accessibility API to set it on the correct item. `[NSAccessibilityUnignoredDescendant(_imageView) setAccessibilityElement:NO]`

Answer (score 1):

If you set an element's accessibility role to an empty string, Voice Over won't detect it. I had to hide some NSImageView  elements in my app because their file names were being read out and it was confusing for the VO user.

Either

`[element accessibilitySetOverrideValue:@"" forAttribute:NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute];`

or else

`[[element cell] accessibilitySetOverrideValue:@"" forAttribute:NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute];`

should do the trick.

I know that Apple a new method based Accessibility API but it only works for OS X 10.10 onwards and the application I'm working needs to be compatible with 10.9.

If you can use the new API
`[element setAccessibilityRole:@""];` or `[[element cell] setAccessibilityRole:@""];` should do the same thing.

Comment: Indeed, [element setAccessibilityRole:@""] works in macOS 10.12 as stated in this answer.   However, the behavior is undocumented.  There are several dozen supported constants listed in NSAccessibilityConstants.h: NSAccessibilityUnknownRole, NSAccessibilityButtonRole, ….  But none of them indicate “not accessible” or “no role”, and none are an empty string.  Conclusion: This behavior could change in a future version of macOS.

Comment: Jerry is right, the "empty role" approach is not ideal. It doesn't work with Switch Control, for one. To hide an image view from accessibility, you just need to set `setAccessibilityElement(false)` on the NSImageViewCell. The same goes for most other controls.