# Making NSSegmentedControl segments accessible

Tags: accessibility, appkit

My AppKit app's `NSSegmentedControl` doesn't show any labels in the Accessibility Inspector, meaning that disabled users won't be able to use assistive devices to interact with them. Calling `setAccessibilityLabel` and `setAccessibilitySelected` on the segment controls has no effect.

Similar advice on the topic (e.g., [Disable / hide accessibility element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523333/disable-hide-accessibility-element/35182395#35182395)) says to use `accessibilitySetOverrideValue`, which *does* work, but it is deprecated:

```
accessibilitySetOverrideValue(_:forAttribute:)' was deprecated in macOS 10.10: Use the NSAccessibility protocol methods instead (see NSAccessibilityProtocols.h)
```

The Apple docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1535843-accessibilitysetoverridevalue read:

```
This method is deprecated. Use the new method-based API instead. For more information, see Accessibility Programming Guide for OS X or NSAccessibilityProtocol.
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any equivalent method to override an accessibility value. How can I accomplish this without using deprecated methods?

Answer (score 0):

NSSegmentedControl will pick up the accessibilityDescription of the image. So the solution I used was to ensure all my segmented controls have images, and for each one, if necessary, make a copy of the image, set the accessibilityDescription explicitly, and reset the image.

Ugly, but better than any other solution I found.